# How to print the data in 3 list on different lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have this python function and will like to print each list on a different line like this with the print(body)

```
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9

        def send_email():
            mylist1 = [1,2,3]
            mylist2 = [4,5,6]
            mylist3 = [7,8,9]

            body = ''

            for item1 in mylist1:  
                body += str(f"{item1}")
            
            for item2 in mylist2:
                body +=  str(item2)

            for item3 in mylist3:
               body += str(item3)


            print(body)

        send_email()
```

How can I format this?

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to assemble the contents of your lists into the `body`. The first (inner) `join` assembles the values of each list (converted to strings, so '1','2' & '3' for `mylist1`) with a comma between them. The second (outer) `join` assembles those strings into a larger string, with newlines between each string.

```py
body = '\n'.join(','.join(str(t) for t in lst) for lst in [mylist1, mylist2, mylist3])
print(body)
```

Output:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line of code in the body variable?

Comment: @Baba see my edit, I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you (assuming you want it in the same method):

```
mylist1 = [1,2,3]
mylist2 = [4,5,6]
mylist3 = [7,8,9]

def print_with_newline(mylist):
  body = ''
  for item in mylist:
    body += str(item) + '\n'
  return body  

body = print_with_newline(mylist1) + print_with_newline(mylist2) + print_with_newline(mylist3)
print(body)
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: This does not work. It listed 1 to 9 vertically.